Loading in Tailwind after JIT?
So I am trying to load in a piece of code I stored in my database, as mentioned in my previous post.
My previous post about this problem: TailwindCSS Colors not working when taking text (Code) from database
The problem is that Tailwinds JIT only adds the styles it sees in my blade file, but my variable "$code" isn't recognized by Tailwind even though the variable code (in this case) contains: "<div class="bg-red-500 text-green-200 text-lg border">Code should be here</div>"
I would like to have Tailwind classes also work for whatever code the $code variable contains.
A safelist wouldnt work, because I dont know what Tailwind classes to expect, and I cant safe list every single class because that would beat the point of Tailwind.
This project uses Laravel, TailwindCSS and raw Javascript.
If something is unclear just post a comment and I can try clarifying.

Tailwind classes have to exist as unbroken strings in your source files, so theres no way to achieve this without including all the potential classes in a safelist. If you REALLY need to, you could use the Play CDN <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> which should inject the CSS dynamically, however it isn't recommended for production.

See https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6105. Maybe consider using the safelist option or even reading the html strings into the raw option if a limited version of classes are stored in the database.  If you are trying to generate any className, I don't know how but maybe you could implement the "Node API" as mentioned in the discussion thread.

My suggestion is, if possible, to store the styles instead of Tailwind classes and then apply them dynamically when the page is rendered. I used this approach for colors and it worked very well

Alright, so a safelist wouldnt work, because any piece of Tailwind code could be stored in the database in this case, CDN is also not an option because this site will be put online available for the public, and the styles as far im aware also isnt possible due to the whole point being that its TailwindCSS, I might try to use javascript to read out classes and apply them somehow, otherwise I will have to resort to hard coding in every single thing im afraid.
